# Is there anyway that we can get a report of incoming calls along with the phone numbers on Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-connect

I'm trying to get a report on Amazon Connect where it would show incoming calls along with the phone numbers. Basically a report of each call. On historical reports, it would only show stats of all calls instead of each calls individually.

Answer (score 0):

The Contact Search will show you this information for a short date range.

[image: Contact Search Menu]

Select initiation method of inbound as the only filter criteria.

[image: Filter Criteria]

You can then export the results to CSV, but unfortunately the export can't be scheduled to S3.

If you needed to have the report scheduled on a regular basis, you would need to leverage the Contact Trace Records (CTR) via Kinesis streaming.  There are 2 options to do this:

1. Set your CTRs to export to a Kinesis Data Stream and then run a Kinesis Data Analytics (KDA) Application against the stream to provide the results of a SQL query as a CSV to S3
2. Set your CTRs to export to a Kinesis Data Firehose, with S3 as the destination, and then use Glue to crawl the exported JSON files and create indexes in Athena.  You can then you query for Athena for the data dynamically.

The second approach would allow you to create the report for an ad-hoc time frame vs. the first options that would limit the KDA solution would produce the reports ever a fixed window that was specified as part of the SQL query.